# Restricting access to specific fields in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, database-schema

I have a `_User` Class in MongoDb for which I do not want sensitive items such as `email` being returned queries (unless the correct session token is sent).

I can set CLP in the `_Schema` like so:

```

```
  "_metadata": {
        "class_permissions": {
            "get": {
                "*": true
            },
            "find": {
                "*": true
            },
            "update": {
                "*": true
            },
            "create": {
                "*": true
            },
            "delete": {
                "*": true
            },
            "addField": {
                "*": true
            },
            "readUserFields": [],
            "writeUserFields": []
        }
    },
    "username": "string",
    "email": "string"...
```

```

I do not want to whole Class to be hidden - i.g., I want to keep `get` and `find` as publicly readable. I just want to hide certain columns.

I couldn't find any documentation on the field `readUserFields` as seen above, nor did it help to add fields within it, i.e. `readUserField: ["trivialField"]`.

If it helps, this database structure was migrated from https://parse.com - but I believe the question is more relevant to MongoDB as a whole; there was no useful information regarding this from the Parse community.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You want to prevent it on any API call or do you want to be able to control on it from the client ?

Comment: Prevent on any API call, unless the correct ACL role is applied. Is that possible?